# Save wanted image pixels in different matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and programming. I have a RGB image of size [640 780]. Now lets say I need only those pixels whose red value is more than 100 and remaining less pixels I convert to 255. Now I would like to know how can I store those needed pixels in a different matrix so that I can use those values to directly navigate in the original RGB picture for drawing an ROI ???

```
a = 1; b = 1;
maybe_red = RGB;
for i = 1:sizeim(1)
     for j = 1:sizeim(2)
if RGB(i,j,1) > 100 
        red_trace_x(a) = i;
        red_trace_y(b) = j;
        b = b+1;
    else
        maybe_red(i,j,:) = 1;
    end
end
a = a+1;
end
```

Currently I am storing `x` and `y` in separate arrays. But I would like to know how to store both `x,y` values in single matrix.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following generates a mask (a logical array of same size as the original image) where pixels with red channel value greater than 100 are stored as 1s and other pixels as 0s:

```
img= imread('peppers.jpg');
mask=img(:,:,1)>100;
```

You can use the mask to index into your original image and make changes to it using `find` to determine the linear indices corresponding to mask pixels with value 1:

```
indlin=find(mask);
img2 = img;
```

You can use the linear indices directly, for instance to saturate the red channel:

```
img2(indlin) = 255;
```

or the green channel:

```
n = numel(img)/3;
img2(indlin+n) = 255;
```

From left to right, the original image, mask, sat'd red, and sat'd green:

[image]

*edit*

You can retrieve array subscripts `ix` and `iy` from the linear indices with

```
[ix iy]=ind2sub(size(mask),indlin);
```

Comment: how would you extract rows n cols from indlin ??

Answer (score 1):

How about if you just store the index of the element?

```
%% Load a sample image
RGB = imread('football.jpg'); 

b = 1; 
maybe_red = RGB;
red = RGB(:,:,1); % Get the red component

% i will represent the index of the matrix
for i = 1:length(red(:))  % length(red(:)) = rows*cols
    if red(i) > 100 
        red_trace(b) = i;
        b = b+1;
    else
        [r,c] = ind2sub(size(red),i);  % Convert the index to rows and cols
        maybe_red(r,c,:) = 1;
    end
end

imshow(maybe_red);
```

but it might just be easier to do

```
red = RGB(:,:,1); % Get the red component of the image
[r,c] = find(red>100);
coord = [r c];
```

Comment: the length(red) is 780 now according to mentioned resolution. so the loop goes for 780 times instead of 640*780 times..?? but it must go through all the rows n col to filter the desired value.

Comment: If your rows=640 and cols = 780, for i = 1:length(red) will loop 640*780 times. Your code loops through the first two dimensions. Is that the intention or do you intend to loop through all dimensions i.e. 640*780*n? The second solution is the preferred one as it will be a lot quicker.

Comment: When i tried in matlab the loops goes for 780 times not more than that.. I did exactly as you mentioned above. but still it does not work.. anything wrong that im doing..??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the colon operator in length(red(:))) but honestly, you shouldn't really be using for loops for this because it is very slow. My second suggestion is the short version of @Try Hard's answer which is the proper way of doing it. It's a lot faster...

Comment: if i want to use other dimensions, still is it possible to use this second method ??

Comment: I found out.. I think i can use the the second method for multiple dimension. I can mask the already masked image with another filter right??

Comment: Do you mean the variable red would have >2 dimensions?